# analysis of matrix multiplication via singular-value-decomposition?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, svd

Consider a square real matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and a real **symmetric** matrix of the same size $\mathbf{S}$

If I can diagonalise $\mathbf{A}$, such that $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$, then I can easily analyse t products of $\mathbf{A}$, that is, $\mathbf{A}^{t}$ as I have $\mathbf{A}^{t}=\mathbf{B}\mathbf{D}^{t}\mathbf{B}^{-1}$.

Is there a "similar" way to simplify $\mathbf{E}(t)=\big(\mathbf{A}^{t}\big)\mathbf{S}\big({\mathbf{A}^{t}}^{T}\big)$, which is symmetric for all $t\geq 0$ ?

PS: from this, my aim is to understand the "behavior" of the sum $\sum_{t\geq 0}\mathbf{E}(t)$

Comment: Do you want to understand the transient behavior or steady-state behavior?

Comment: mainly the steady-state, but transient behavior would be a plus too (-;

Comment: And just to be clear, the $\mathbf{A}$ matrix in the $\mathbf{E}(t)$ function may not be diagonalisable (actually in the particular case I am considering it is not) but of course $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{A}^{T}$ is, as is $\mathbf{S}$ as both are symetrical (and real, non-negative)

Answer (score 1):

We can vectorize $E(t)$ as

$$ \operatorname{vec}(E(t)) = (A^t \otimes A^t) \operatorname{vec}(S) = (A \otimes A)^t \operatorname{vec}(S) $$

where $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product. If $A$ has eigenvalues in the unit circle, then the sum converges. Therefore,

$$ \operatorname{vec} \left(\sum_{t\geq0} E(t) \right) = (I - A \otimes A)^{-1} \operatorname{vec}(S) $$

Of course you can make calculations much easier by using decompositions of $A$. In particular, you can use Schur decomposition to make $A$ upper triangular and easily solve

$$ (I - A \otimes A) \operatorname{vec} \left(\sum_{t\geq0} E(t) \right) = \operatorname{vec}(S) $$

for the elements of the sum one by one.

Another alternative would be using SVD of $A$.

**Edit.** Another approach would be solving the following equivalent Lyapunov equation:

$$ E - A E A^T = S $$

where $E := \sum_{t\geq0} E(t)$.

Comment: thanks a lot @obareey ! How would that work with the SVD of $\mathbf{A}$ ? I have tried this route (intuitively it seems quite promising) but I can't get a simple formula because of the powers of t.

Comment: I'm not sure what you seek, but SVD can be used in the sense that it is a well-known and stable method for solving linear equations. There are so many other methods exist such as QR decomposition, LU decomposition, etc., which are suitable for some cases and not suitable for others. Also, see my edit.

Comment: thanks a million @obareey,  this "Lyapunov Equation" link is exactly what I need. I will know read more about that.  Without you I would never have found it !